# Changing the suffix of .pdf causes it not to be opened correctly in windows

Tags: file-extension

My dilemma is that there is pdf file named 'P01111-AMFLIBL.pdf' , I want to append '.NOSUFFIX' after .pdf so the result will be like 'P01111-AMFLIBL.pdf.NOSUFFIX'.

I am trying to add by this line of code :

```
fileName = fileName + ".pdf" + ".NOSUFFIX";
```

It's working, but the problem is that pdf file is not directly getting opened into my system

[image: snapshot]

Comment: If your system is Windows, it decides how to open the file by its extension. If you add the suffix, you're effectively changing the extension and the system won't know how to open it.

Comment: Is there anyway i can keep the file as pdf and still append the.NOSUFFIX at the end after .pdf extension in java ?

Comment: No. On Windows, the suffix determines the file type. You can do `file.NOSUFFIX.pdf`, but that's about it.

Comment: Why are  you doing this? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, the extension (i.e. suffix starting at last `.`) determines the file type (and associated program). If you append another suffix, this appended `.NOSUFFIX` will become the file extension, and the original `.pdf` will become just a part of the file name.

Comment: If the file ''file.pdf.NOSUFFIX" is sent via sftp drop to linux then ?

Comment: Linux uses different method to determine the content type (based on content of the file), so it should treat it as PDF.

Comment: i have sent the file to Linux via sftp drop, file reach there in correct format , Thanks